# Get text under Paragraph programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a large word document which contains some headings. These headings have respectively one table as a child. (depicted in the screenshot)

[image]

Therefore I used the Microsoft Interop.Word library. My code looks like this. How can I get the children of a heading paragraph? Maybe there's a better way of doing this.

```
Application word = new Application();
Document doc = new Document();
object missing = System.Type.Missing;
doc = word.Documents.Open(ref m_FileName,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

foreach (Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
{
    Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
    string text = paragraph.Range.Text;
    paragraph.Range.Tables // does not get the table under the paragraph
}
```

Comment: A Word document is not hierarchical in its internal structure but rather a sequence of block-level elements such as paragraphs and tables. Therefore the heading paragraph does not contain the table.

In your case it means that you need to access the paragraph following the heading (or you could also simply iterate over all tables in the document using `doc.Tables`)

Comment: As an aside: Since .NET 4 you can write your code much more compact, there is no need to specify all the missing parameters and to use `ref`. You can simply write: `word.Document.Open(m_FileName);`

Comment: @dirk vollmar But I need the heading as a key for the table. There needs to be a way of doing this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve? It's pretty unclear what your requirements are.

Comment: @dirkVollmar I try to elaborate. My requirements are that the table logically belongs to a heading. My written parser in C# should now find some headings with a specific name. This works so far. Every found heading has a table directly under this heading. Now I want to get the information in the table mapped to the name of the heading where it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it using ranges. Find first title, find next title (or anything you can use as an end of the chapter and get the content in between:

```
Range r1 = doc.Content; 
Range r2 = doc.Content; 
r1.Find.Execute("Heading 1"); 
r2.Find.Execute("Heading 2");

Range chapter = doc.Range(r1.Start, r2.Start); 
//Console.WriteLine(chapter.Text);

foreach (Table t in chapter.Tables)
{
    foreach(Row r in t.Rows)
    {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Cells)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(c.Range.Text);
        }
    }
}
```